# visual studio 2019にて未解決の外部シンボル(VerQueryValueW)・(GetFileVersionInfoW)・(GetFileVersionInfoSizeW)の参照エラーを修正できない。

Tags: c++

リソースからバージョンを取得するために以下リンク先のソースコードを使用してみたのですが、タイトルのようなエラーが発生しています。

[C++でバージョン情報を取得する](https://araramistudio.jimdo.com/2017/05/19/c-%E3%81%A7%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/)

色々なファイルのインクルードもしてみたり、他の似たようなサイトで調べたりもしましたが、解決できておりません。
ご助力の程宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

> 未解決の外部シンボル(VerQueryValueW)・(GetFileVersionInfoW)・(GetFileVersionInfoSizeW)の参照エラー

「未解決の外部シンボル～」といったエラーメッセージは、コンパイル時ではなくリンク時の問題を示しています。

例えば[`GetFileVersionInfoW`関数の仕様](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-getfileversioninfow#requirements)をドキュメントで確認すると、ソースコードから#includeすべきヘッダファイルは`Windows.h`を、リンク時に追加指定するライブラリファイルは`Version.lib`が必要なことが分かります。

> Header:   winver.h (include Windows.h)
> Library:  Version.lib

Comment: 分かりました。ご説明していただきありがとうございます。今後は、ドキュメントも確認していこうと思います。

Answer (score 1):

こういう時は公式ページ (Microsoft MSDN) を見る癖をつけてください。 Google でも Bing でもいいので `VerQueryValue` を検索し Microsoft の解説ページを見つけます。
[VerQueryValueW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-verqueryvaluew)
すると Requirement の欄に `Header` と `Library` の解説があります。

（今回は該当しませんが）コンパイル時に未宣言シンボルというエラーが出るときは、ソースコード上 `Header` の追加が抜けています。適切なところに `#include` を追加します。この例の場合、解説ページの読み方が難しいのですが `#include <windows.h>` しろと書かれています（宣言自体は `winver.h` にあるのですが、直接 `#include <winver.h>` するのではなく `#include <windows.h>` しろと指定されています）
# プリコンパイルヘッダを使っている場合などには「適切」がどこかは悩ましい

（今回はこちらが該当）リンク時に未解決シンボルがあるエラーの場合は解説ページ上 `Library` を追加します。 `version.lib` を追加しろとの解説がありますね。ではどうやって追加するか、ですが VS2019 の IDE 画面上のメニューバー プロジェクト(P) → プロパティ (P) から追加します。プロパティページ画面が開くので左ペイン「リンカー→入力」を選ぶと右ペインに「追加の依存ファイル」がたくさん並んでいるはず。ここに `version.lib` が無いはずなので、適当な場所に追加します。よく見ると区切り記号は `;` なことがわかるので `version.lib;kernel32.lib;....` のように追加することでリンクが通るようになります（最初に追加するか末尾に追加するかで意味が違いますが、この例ではどちらでも可）

ところがこのプロパティページ、よく見ると上のほうに「構成」と「プラットフォーム」というのがあります。「構成」には `Debug` と `Release` が、「プラットフォーム」には `Win32` と `x64` があります（ `x64` は出ない場合もあります）２種類ｘ２種類で４つのプロパティページのすべてに追加変更を行っておくことをお勧めします。

Comment: 分かりました。大変丁寧にご説明していただきありがとうございます。以後は公式ページ を見る癖をつけようと思います。

Answer (score 1):

原因や対処については既に回答されている通りですが、対処については Visual C++ 限定で簡略化出来る方法があります。

こちらの記事で解説されているもので、プリプロセッサへの指令でリンクするライブラリをソースコードに明記する方法です。
[comment pragma](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?view=msvc-170)
[lib](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?view=msvc-170#lib)

> オブジェクト ファイル内にライブラリ検索レコードを配置します。

[例](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?view=msvc-170#examples)

> #pragma comment( lib, "emapi" )

上記を適用して質問内容に合わせると、ソースコード上の`#include`等に続けて以下を記述しておけば、プロジェクトのプロパティに幾つのプラットフォーム(Win32/x86/x64/他)や構成(Debug/Release/他)の別が有るかを気にせずどのようなモードを選んでもビルド出来ます。

```
#pragma comment( lib, "version" )
```

Comment: かつて Debug/Release とシングル/マルチスレッドLIB/マルチスレッドDLL で全部ライブラリ名が違うというイヤンな思い出があるので、この方法はオイラ個人的には封印中。今回の件に関しては問題ないのですが。サードパーティライブラリで全部名前が違っているものとかで行数使いたくないです。

Comment: あ～、歴史的経緯とか考慮不足のサードパーティとか確かにありそうですね。ライブラリとSDKを作って配布する際にきちんとディレクトリ名とプロジェクトファイル内の指定マクロが対応するように考慮していれば出来るはずなのですが、そもそも知識が無かったりあっても配慮に欠ける造りをしてる可能性は結構ありそうですからね。

Comment: 分かりました。ご説明ありがとうございます。メリットデメリットも確認できて大変助かりました。